# Is it possible to get the caption property of a label control in AutoIT?

Tags: autoit

I'm (trying to) use AutoIT to automate some test cases. Ideally I would:

1. Open up a windows form
2. Plug in some values
3. Click a button
4. Check to see if the correct results appear in a Label control

I can do 1-3 but I can't see a way to get the caption of a label control.

After some digging I have found https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlCommand.htm which allows me to get some additional properties (such as IsEnabled or IsChecked). Are there any generic property fetches / ways to get the caption or other properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function ControlGetText() will return the caption or text of the specified control.

The function ControlCommand() can be used to get a few other properties depending on the control type.

Custom controls may resist automation - you may not be able to get the values you are after.